# Add constraint foreign key to entity in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've an entity called `Profile`, whose primary key should actually be a foreign key pointing to a `RegisteredUser`.

Currently, this is how I'm trying to say that a field in `Profile` is both its primary and foreign key referencing `RegisteredUser`:

```
@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "REGISTERED_USER_FK"))
private RegisteredUser registeredUser;
```

and in the `RegisteredUser` entity, I have the following:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "registeredUser")
private Profile profile;
```

Unfortunately when I run SpringBootApplication, I've the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'registered_user_username' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

when I try to run this code:

```
User user = new User("blah");
repo.save(user); // using repositories to store entities to the db

Profile profile = new Profile(user.getFirstName());

RegisteredUser rUser = new RegisteredUser(user.getUsername(), profile);
rur.save(rUser);
```

I've checked to see if the username of user is null, but it isn't...The problem is when I save `rUser`...

Comment: The column `registered_user_username` belongs to which entity, `RegisteredUser`?

Comment: Why do you separate Profile from User? Can Profile exist without User object?

Comment: @aribeiro There's no such a column. I've a field in `RegisteredUser` called `username` which also should be the primary key of `RegisteredUser` but should also be a foreign key referencing the primary key of the `User`...

Comment: @Funtik Indeed, it should be a weak entity whose primary key is a foreign key referencing a `RegisteredUser`

Comment: @nbro, then, on your database, the attribute `username` of your `RegisteredUser` is mapped to which column? Can you please update your question with the `RegisteredUser` entity?

Comment: MySQL clearly states you are trying to insert or update `registered_user_username` so if that column does not exist: Check your JPA model.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JPA spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html), you cannot annotate `RegisteredUser` with `@Id` annotation.

I cannot imagine why you need to separate Profile from User, but if you really need to do so you have several options:

**Option A:**

Use `@Embeddable` annotation on `Profile`. You won't get a separate table for `Profile` entity, but you will get a separate object in Java.

**Option B:**

Use `@ManyToOne` on `Profile`. So the lifecycle of user will be something like this:

- Create user
- Create profile
- Save profile
- Set user's profile to saved profile
- Save user

You can even have the same primary keys on those objects (look for suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002260/manually-specify-the-value-of-a-primary-key-in-jpa-generatedvalue-column))

**Option C:**

Configure `@OneToOne`, but forget about the requirement of having both entities having the same primary key.